# Returning function for further use, but without store the older result

Tags: javascript, closures

i'm trying to do the following:

```
function sum(a) {
 return function (b) {
  console.log(a + b);
 }
}
var mySum = sum(10);
mySum(15);
```

output:

```
25
```

Without storing the first result, so the second function kind replaces the first one:

```
function sum(a) {
 return function (b) {
  console.log(a + b);
 }
}
sum(10);
sum(15);
```

output would be:

```
25
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** It is possible. Just change the reference of `sum` when it executes first to the inner function. As shown below

```
function sum(a) {
 sum = function (b) {   // here first time sum executes, it changes its reference
  console.log(a + b);
 }
}
```

Output

```
sum(10);
sum(5);   --> 15
```

---

**Comments** : It is working in nodeJS too

[image]

As discussed in the chat, the issue while using **NodeJS Modules** was with the variable reference `sum`. In our program we are using sum reference to point different function instance after 1st time execution. But the `require` will get the reference of sum and in that file we are pointing it using another reference variable. When we call using that other reference variable, it will not update its reference as reference `sum` does. Below code is the workaround for that

sum.js

```
exports.sum = function(a) { 
  exports.sum = function (b) { 
         // here first time sum executes, it changes its reference 
    console.log(a + b); 
  } 
}
```

run.js

```
var sumFunction = require('./sum.js');
sumFunction.sum(10);
sumFunction.sum(5);     //15
```

I recommend not to use this pattern, because this will add more ambiguity in code. The 1st pattern in your question is the right way to solve this kind of problem. If at all I find any better patterns, I'll update this answer.

Comment: Hm, what's strange.. i'm using like that in node.js and is not working at all @rajuGT

Comment: Oh! It works in browser. Okay, try this instead of named function `function sum(a) {` change it to `var sum = function(a) {` and let me know if it works.

Comment: It is working for me in nodeJS(attached snapshot) and firebug/devtools too.

Comment: that's so strange, i'm literally copying and pasting your code in my atom

Comment: now is printing TypeError: Assignment to constant variable., but i don't have any constants..

Answer (score 0):

Solution with function and property, for keeping the result. The property is public.

```js
function sum(a) {            
    sum.sum = (sum.sum || 0) + a;
    document.write(sum.sum + '<br>');
}
sum(10);
sum(15);
document.write(sum.sum + '<br>');
```

Or use a closure

```js
var sum = function () {
    var a = 0;
    return function (b) {
        a += b;
        document.write(a + '<br>');
    }
}();

sum(10);
sum(15);
```